# `cv2.waitKey(7) & 0xFF` always returns 225, not equal to 113 for 'q' key press

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently working on a Python project that involves capturing video using OpenCV (`cv2`). I've encountered an issue with the `cv2.waitKey` function, and I'm seeking help to understand why it's behaving unexpectedly.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import cv2

videos = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
videos.set(5, 3840)
videos.set(8, 2160)
videos.set(10, 10000)

while True:
    success, img = videos.read()
    cv2.imshow("output", img)
    
    key = cv2.waitKey(7) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

videos.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In this code, I'm trying to break out of the loop when the 'q' key is pressed. However, the condition `cv2.waitKey(7) & 0xFF` is always returning 225, which is not equal to the ASCII value of 'q' (113).

I have tried in some other ways, such as printing the condition in the if statement

```
import cv2
videos = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
videos.set(5,3840)
videos.set(8,2160)
videos.set(10,10000)
while True:
    sucess, img = videos.read()
    cv2.imshow("output", img)
    if print(cv2.waitKey(7)&0XFF) or cv2.waitKey(7) & 0XFF == ord("q") :
        
        break
```

But it still evaluates as false. However, it maanages to enter the if statement and breaks the loop. I would appreciate it if someone tells me why it behaves like this and also enlightens me about `waitKey()`. Thank you in advance

Comment: Both of them are working..The second script can see 113 when pressed 'q'.

Comment: yes Sir it works but when I used to print the condition ( if print(cv2.waitKey(7)&0XFF) or cv2.waitKey(7) & 0XFF == ord("q")  )it shows false that's what i'm asking

Comment: You can see '113'.

Comment: 255
255
113
255

Comment: @toyotaSupra 255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255              ---------- this is what I got as output

Comment: I'm using Python 3.12.0rc3. Worked for both Windows 10 and Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`225` is a typo.

You mean `255`.

That happens when the function `waitKey()` times out (you gave it about 7 milliseconds of time) and returns -1, which signifies "no key pressed".

The superfluous calculation of `& 0xff` then turns `-1` into `255`. It is superfluous because that's already done *in the API itself* since the end of 2016. It is also wrong to do this yourself because now you can't tell if the function returned -1 or an actual key value (0 .. 255).

When `waitKey()` returns -1, you're supposed to do nothing. No key was pressed.

You can write the code like so:

```py
...

assert videos.isOpened() # important!

while True:
    success, img = videos.read()
    if not success: # important! that indicates an error
        break

    cv2.imshow("output", img)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) # or: key = cv2.pollKey()
    if key == -1: # no key event
        continue

    print(f"keycode: 0x{key:02x}")

    if key == ord('q'):
        break
```

Also, your cap props are completely wrong. Never ever use magic numbers. Use named constants (whichever you need):

- `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH`
- `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT`
- `cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS`
- `cv2.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS`